# vBulletin attachments table structure

Tags: php, vbulletin

I am importing posts from a custom forum to vBulletin 4. I have done most of the work. Now only photos/videos needs to be copied.

For that I will replace [img] tags (old Forum tags) to vBulletin tags such as [ATTACH]ID[/ATTACH]. But I need to know how does vB manages attachments? What is the table structure? Which tables are involved?

So far I have found that following tables are involved

filedata

attachmentcategoryuser

attachment

Comment: This question would be better asked on the VBulletin support forums. As far as getting an answer on its vB inner-workings.

Comment: Ok. I have put this question VB forums too. Thanks.